# Compiling with MingW in CMD shows libisl-21.dll was not found

Tags: c++, mingw

I was trying to compile a `.cpp` file using command-line, but I am encountering an error.

I have installed MinGW properly from the official installer.
Also, I sat the path to the bin folder of MinGW which is in C drive.

Now when I try to compile file with command:

```
g++ demo.cpp -o demo.exe
```

I get a "CC1plus.exe - System error" message-box, like:

```
The code execution cannot proceed because libisl-21.dll was not found.
Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

I can't find the .dll file anywhere. What seems to be going wrong? Any lead? I have reinstalled MinGW multiple times.

Thanks,

Comment: Show code and errors, don't attach images.

Comment: Hint, to get an error from a message box as text you can press ctrl+c and you'll hear a ding sound to confirm it was copied.

Comment: I am sorry that I attached images. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libisl-*.dll` is part of the MinGW-w64 distribution.

I'm not sure older MinGW also provides it, but you should use MinGW-w64 anyway (e.g. from https://winlibs.com/ or installed via [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/)'s `pacman`) as it's much better maintained and supports newer Windows versions (including 64-bit).

Your problem is that `g++.exe` depends on `libisl-21.dll` but can't find it.

Check the following:

- From which location is `g++.exe` being called? This should be the first location containing `g++.exe` in the `PATH` environment variable in the environment where you were running `g++.exe` from (e.g. if this is the Command Prompt type `ECHO %PATH%` to see its value).
- Does the folder containing `g++.exe` also contain `libisl-21.dll`?
- Is your MinGW setup broken or can it be uninstalled+reinstalled?
- Do you have multiple MinGW / MinGW-w64 installations on your system that are getting mixed up (e.g. because multiple are point to via the `PATH` environment variable)?
- You can try to unpack a standalone MinGW-w64 from https://winlibs.com/ - which doesn't have an installer and will not interfere with your other installed MinGW(-w64) releases - and try to use `g++.exe` from its `bin` folder by specifying it's entire path.

Comment: Thank you. It solved when I re-installed from a different source.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an embedded program, but want to test out code snippets on g++ on Windows because it's much faster than building & loading on the embedded system itself. Our embedded system's unittests run on `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc\g++.exe`, so that's the copy of g++ I was trying to use when I had this problem. Using hints from Brecht Sanders's answer, this solved my problem:

In a "build.bat" file I created local to my code snippet "ftest.cpp" file:

```
@setlocal
@set ORIGINAL_PATH_VARIABLE=%PATH%
@set PATH=C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\bin\gcc;%ORIGINAL_PATH_VARIABLE%

g++ -std=gnu++11 -g -Wall -Werror ftest.cpp
```

(I searched for and found libisl-21.dll at `C:\MinGW\bin`.)

Hopefully someone finds this helpful.